# Which machine learning model should be used in this situation?

Tags: machine-learning

Recently I'm working on my course project, it's an android app that can automatically help fill consuming form based on the user's voice. So here is one sample sentence:
[image]

So what I want to do is let the app fill forms automatically, my forms have several fields: time(yesterday), location(MacDonald), cost(10 dollars), type(food). Here the "type" field will include food, shopping, transport, etc.

I have used the word-splitting library to split the sentence into several parts and parse it, so I can already extract the time, location and cost fields from the user's voice.

What I want to do is deduce the "type" field with some kind of machine learning model. So there should be some records in advance, input by user manually to train the model. After training, when new record comes in, I first extract the time, location and cost fields, and then calculate the type field based on the model.

But I don't know how to represent the location field, should I use a dictionary to include many famous locations and use index to represent the location? If so, which kind of machine learning method should I use to model this requirement?

Comment: You need to check out **Natural Language Processing**. see also: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Comment: @mskimm I've already used word-splitting library to split the sentence and can get the time, cost, location field, but I do not know how what machine learning model should I use to deduce the "type" field.

Comment: You want to look for information extraction. This is a sequence tagging problem---take a look at conditional random fields as a technique

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the Naive Bayes classifier. The links below should be useful in understanding it:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier
- http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html

I wonder if time and cost are that discriminative/informative in comparison to location for your task.

In general, look at the following link on working with text data (it should be useful even if you dont know python):

- http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 0):

It should include three stages:

1. Feature Representation:

One way to represent the features is the Bag-of-Word representation, which you fix an order of the dictionary and use a word frequency vector to represent the documents. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model for details.

1. Data and Label Collection:

Basically, in this stage, you should prepare some [feature]-[type] pairs to training your model, which can be tedious or expensive. If you had already published your app, and collected a lot of [sentence]-[type] pair (probably chosen by app user), you can extract the features and build a training set.

1. Model Learning:

Cdeepakroy has suggested a good choice of the model: Naive Bayes, which is very efficient for classification task like this. At this stage, you can just find a suitable package, insert your training data, and enjoy the classifier it returns.